# Can not get session variable return from Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am learning Laravel, I'm trying to put a success message to the session and get in view to display, but it seems didn't work

Here is my code in the view section

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-12">
            @if (session()->has('msg'))
                <h5> {{ session('msg') }}</h5>
            @endif
```

And here is the Controller function that I used to add new and put messages to the session

```
public function store(CatalogRequest $request)
{

    $status=$this->catalog->insert([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'status' => $request->status
    ]);

    if($status){
        $msg = "Add Catalog Successfullly";
        $color = 'success';
    }else{
        $msg = "Add Catalog failed";
        $color = 'red';
    }

    session()->put('msg',$msg);

    return redirect('catalog');
}
```